# Create soap service

Tags: grails, soap, grails-plugin

I need create soap service. I use grails 3.2. This is one of the [solutions](http://docs.grails.org/2.1.0/guide/webServices.html#SOAP). I use [cxf plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/ctoestreich/cxf), but I get an errorr:

> [Fatal Error] cxf-3.1.1.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'testGrails12'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
>   >     Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:cxf:3.1.1.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          testgrails12:testGrails12:0.1
>   >     Could not resolve org.grails.plugins:cxf:3.1.1.
>   >     Could not parse POM https ://repo.grails. org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cxf/3.1.1/cxf-3.1.1.pom
>   >     Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> CONFIGURE FAILED
>   * Try:
>
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output. Total time: 19.337 secs
>   Error | Error initializing classpath: Content is not allowed in
>   prolog. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I tried to use this plugin (http:// plugins. grails. org/plugin/ctoestreich/cxf-client)
I get an errorr:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>
>   > A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe''
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Error | Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I need create soap secvices. I will consider various solutions.

Comment: Can you post the pom.xml file? does it open in browser correctly?

Comment: @Rao Links are separated by spaces, because I can not use more than 2 links

Comment: You can see for yourself https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/cxf/3.1.1/cxf-3.1.1.pom